# data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has wrong ownership

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

When I put `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` in terminal, I get this back:

FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.

How could I fix with that?
Thanks~

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the what the owner is of that dir by doing

```
ls -l /usr/local/var/ | grep postgres
```

You should see something like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgresuser postgresuser  285659 Sep  1 18:05 postgres
```

Assuming it's "postgresuser", then run your database with

```
sudo -u postgresuser postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Comment: I try the first line, but the result I got was drwxr--r--+ 27 root  admin  918  1 28 23:31 postgres

Comment: but it says "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.

Comment: Run `sudo chown -R YYY /usr/local/var/postgres` replacing `YYY` with your user name. Then you should be able to run `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`.

Comment: and then I got FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has group or world access
DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700). how could I change it....

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 700 /usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: but FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 7671) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?

Comment: It's mentioning that postgresql may already be running, check if `ps -e | grep 7671` returns anything.

Comment: It returns "7671 ??         0:00.02 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
 7685 ttys000    0:00.00 grep 7671" what does it mean?

Comment: It means your database is running - you should be able to use it