# Cannot connect to Postgres server running through brew services

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I've been looking for a solution for this and could not find a working solution.

I've installed postgres using brew (`brew install postgres`)  in my MacBook and I am currently running it using brew services (`brew services list`  displays postgres as a running service). However, when I try to run `psql` I get following error.

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Anyone has already solved similar problem?

Comment: Both the question and the answers here are very helpful.

Answer (score 479, accepted):

I had the same error and I fixed it by removing the process pid file:

`rm -f /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

**or** for a specific version:

`rm -f /usr/local/var/postgresql@16/postmaster.pid`

---

[Updated Answer For Arm-based Chips (Apple M1)]

When you use `brew` to install `postgresql` on Apple M1 computers, the `postmaster.pid` will be located in:
`/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql/postmaster.pid`

Follow following three steps:

```bash
# 1. Stop PostgreSQL 
brew services stop postgresql@16

# 2. Delete the postmaster.pid
rm -f /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@16/postmaster.pid

# 3. Start the PostgreSQL again
brew services start postgresql@16
```

After the above, you can also check the status of the service by `brew services info postgresql`

```bash
brew services info postgresql@16
postgresql@16 (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
Running: ✔
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
User: root
PID: 34884
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But why? How? Do I have run this command after every restart?

Comment: @rap-2-h It seems that Postgres isn't being shut down properly. I get this problem when I have to shutdown my Mac by holding the power button.

Comment: If you use keg of specific version (example: postgresql@9.6) make sure to use correct folder instead of "/postgres/"

Comment: Indeed this is related to postgres not being shut down properly by macOS but for me, it even happened when I used the Apple menu + "Shut down..." option so it is not specifically related to force shut down (anymore at least, macOS 10.14.3). This fixed it, thumbs up (y)

Comment: If this doesn't work, try  `tail /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`. This may give you more information about exactly why postgres is failing. You can usually post the error message from that log in google, and find another fix on StackOverflow :-D

Comment: For Apple Silicone Macs use `rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` as the brew folder is by default in a `/opt/homebrew` instead of `/usr/local`.

Comment: `rm -f /usr/local/var/postgres@[version #]/postmaster.pid` in cases where different versions are installed by homebrew

Comment: Why did you include `-f`? Works without it on my mac.

Comment: For v14: `rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid`

Comment: Oh man, thanks sooo much! This worked when nothing else did.

Comment: I'm trying to follow these steps, but I do not have a file 'postmaster.pid' file in my opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14 folder.  I am getting the same error mentioned in the title, though. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried all the suggestions but in the end this worked for me ```pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14 start```

Comment: Thank you you hero! The M1 commands were what I needed!

Answer (score 160):

I ran into this problem today. postgres stopped accepting connections though homebrew thought it was running.

To fix it I ran,

```
brew services restart -vvv postgresql
```

Output from this command,

```
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Generated plist for postgresql:
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
     <key>KeepAlive</key>
     <true/>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql</string>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
       <string>/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres</string>
       <string>-D</string>
       <string>/usr/local/var/postgres</string>
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
     <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
     <string>/usr/local</string>
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
```

Then I thought, hmm maybe there's something in that log file,

```
tail -n 10 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

Sure enough,

```
[4826] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
[4826] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1489) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

So, I removed that file

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

And everything started working again.

Comment: The most useful command for me was `tail -n 10 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`

Comment: On M1 `tail -n 10 /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgres.log`

Comment: `brew services restart -vvv postgresql` worked great for me

Comment: Very helpful step-by-step @Eric Conner! I repeated the approach, and it led me to a different root cause in my case:

`2023-09-26 17:41:41.047 EDT [6620] FATAL:  data directory "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15" has invalid permissions`

`2023-09-26 17:41:41.047 EDT [6620] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).`


I did `sudo chmod -R 0700 /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15` and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 60):

In my case the `postmaster.pid` file wasn't even there. Got it working by upgrading postgres.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Then, because I upgraded the major version from 10 to 11, I also had to run this:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

(source https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18760#issuecomment-410533581)

Comment: In these cases, the `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` file may have this as the last few logs:


`FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server`

`DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 12.2.`

Comment: I got this exact problem. The upgrade from postgresql 11 to 12 failed, but uninstalling and installing again helped through.

Comment: `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 29):

I would combine the two answers from Wilson and Grasshopper here.

You can check the plist file for the postgres service using `brew services list` to find the location of the file and just opening it up in you favourite editor.

You should see the value of `StandardErrorPath` listed as:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log</string>
```

And then you should tail the end of the log file using `tail -n 100 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`

In my case the error was the following:

> 2017-12-06 11:51:16.078 GMT [85476] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
>   2017-12-06 11:51:16.078 GMT [85476] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 601) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?

This was because I had to hard shutdown my Mac and postgres didn't get a chance to cleanup the PID file. Just remove the PID file `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` and start postgres `brew services start postgresql`

A word of warning: **do not delete this PID file unless you are sure that postgres is not running**. You can do this by running `brew services stop postgresql` and then waiting for the result of `brew services list` to show posgres is in the stopped state.

Answer (score 15):

**Problem - Postgres not working after macOS upgrade**

I just upgraded to the latest macOS (Big Sur).

My node application that uses a local instance of *postgresql* as a database was unable to start due to this error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`

Clearly *postgresql* is no longer running properly on my machine.

Running `brew services list` shows an error for *postgresql*:

```
Name          Status  User  Plist    
postgresql    error   ***** /Users/*****/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

**Solution - Upgrade Postgres**

To resolve the problem I upgraded *postgresql* with the following commands:

```
$ brew services stop postgresql
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database # may need to `rm-rf /usr/local/var/postgres.old` first
$ brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: this did the trick `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`
thanks

Comment: I was able to remove the postgres.old directory by using ```rm -r /usr/local/var/postgres.old```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error when I forced the restart of my mac.

When I did:

```
brew services list
```

I got this error:

```
postgresql        error  256 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Steps followed to resolve this issue:

Open the terminal and type the following command.

```
cd /opt/homebrew/var/postgres
rm postmaster.pid
```

Answer (score 10):

In case you have multiple versions of postgresql installed. Below mentioned commands will do the job of removing process id(pid) and restarting it. Just make sure you select the correct version.

```
rm -f /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6/postmaster.pid

brew services restart postgresql@9.6
```

Please also refer to Eric Corner's answer to confirm if the issue is about "lock file postmaster.pid already exists" in log file.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. I was trying endlessly for 2hr+ but it was saying no such file found. Then I looked at this and specified the version as well. And voila! it worked

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was removing the `/usr/local/var/postgres/` folder and then uninstalling and installing postgres again

Comment: You should try other responses before doing this.

Comment: Will this not delete the entire database?

Answer (score 7):

In my case after updating to MacOS Monterey it was need to make

```
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

as well.

Comment: Crazy, but that worked.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error installing postgresql93 from the versions tap.
Inspecting the .plist file indicated in the output of `brew services list`(`~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql93.plist`) I found the following message:

> FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has group or world access
>   DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).

Which led me to this answer: [data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has wrong ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078217/data-directory-usr-local-var-postgres-has-wrong-ownership)

After running `sudo chmod -R 700 /usr/local/var/postgres` I got a different error:

> FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory

Which then led me to: [`pg_tblspc` missing after installation of latest version of OS X (Yosemite or El Capitan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-latest-version-of-os-x-yosemite-or-el)

After running `mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_tblspc/` the cluster started successfully.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (postgres installed by homebrew),

- tailing the log to see what the error was `tail -n 50 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`

  2022-04-28 16:38:10.509 PDT [84751] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
  2022-04-28 16:38:10.509 PDT [84751] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 969) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
- kill the `pid` based on above `kill -9 <pid>`
- restart the service via homebrew `brew services restart postgresql && brew services list`

Answer (score 3):

If using homebrew on macos, you can check the logs:

```
# change @15 by the version you have installed
# run this if you want to check what you have
# `brew list | grep postgres`
tail -n 100 /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@15.log
```

In my case I saw errors like this:

```
2023-10-24 14:43:01.793 -03 [54662] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2023-10-24 14:43:01.793 -03 [54662] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 10344) running in data directory "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15"?
```

Removing the lock did the trick:
`rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/postmaster.pid`

Then running `psql` to assert it works:
`psql -d postgres`

Comment: Depending on your macOS version this could be another possible location for your postmaster.pid `/usr/local/var/postgresql@12/postmaster.pid`

Answer (score 2):

update it by using command

```
  brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

if you have following error 
**Command 'brew' not found,** **but can be installed with:
sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper**

then install it by using command

```
 sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

In case all the other answers don't work...

I was seeing this same message and the accepted answer, running

`rm -f /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

didn't work. Neither did

`rm -f /usr/local/var/postgres@9.6/postmaster.pid` after I remembered I had a specific version installed.

I did a `cat /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@9.6.log` and saw:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1231) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6"?
```

```
> ps aux|grep 1231
[...] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/mobileassetd
```

**thinking face**

**Closed the iOS Simulator. Postgres restarted on its own.**

This is on a desktop and we had the power go out yesterday, so based on the other answers I suspect the root cause is the hard shutdown without giving things a chance to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

If your postgres.log file contains "image not found error" then you may need to reinstall postgresql:

```
brew reinstall postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone scrolls to the bottom after trying everything out and it's not working, this is what worked for me. I decided not to use brew for this eventually.

I installed Postgres app directly from the website following this link https://postgresapp.com, initialised a new server and created the databases and tables as usual.

I was also getting port occupied related errors and this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825665 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was a non-versioned Postgres directory after I assume a version 14 dot upgrade.

```
brew info postgresql
```

gives a warning about the non-versioned directory and says to run:

```
brew services stop postgresql
mv -v "/opt/homebrew/var/postgres" "/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, the `postgres.log` file contains this `HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, remove socket file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" and retry.` After removing the socket file and restarting, everything worked fine. Note that this is a hidden file and won't be visible through the window browser. Removal should be done via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an open connection to my database.

Answer (score -1):

You might be seeing a conflict of libssl/libcrypto versions.

`brew services start postgres` logs gave me nada, but manually starting `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` pointed at:

missing definition _RAND_cleanup in /.../openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Have a shot at:

```
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl
brew install openssl@1.0.2t

# and then either brew link openssl@1.0.2t or symlink the required files to current openssl
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/openssl@1.0.2t/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/openssl@1.0.2t/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the problem was that I was attempting to start the `brew` service in an SSH session on a Mac, where my user was not currently logged in. Simply logging into the Mac, through the MacOS login GUI solved the issue.

A more detailed error message included the hint that the problem was `gui`-related:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl enable gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql` exited with 64.
```

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that another postgres was running in the background I don't know why, you can check it with the command:
`sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :5432`
and then kill this process if you don't need it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find the correct log location in the answer above. Probably because the brew installation path of the M1 chip is different from inter.

My log is located in `/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log`